# Is erlang considered managed or do you have to handle memory/pointers?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

Is erlang considered managed or do you have to handle memory/pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to Craig Stuntz](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/01/24/37787/), *all functional languages* use garbage collection, which essentially means that they are managed languages.  Functional programming features do not work well with the semantics of explicit memory release.

**Garbage Collection in Erlang**
http://prog21.dadgum.com/16.html

Answer (score 4):

I can assure you, you don't have to deal with pointers in Erlang as there is none of these (yeah!).